# Wages historical data

Tags: wages, data

I would need some free data on both average real and nominal wages growth rates for a panel of 100 countries from post war to current . I have looked at the world Bank, UN and ilo but the series is limited for time span and sample. . Any help would be much appreciated where to find them

Comment: To my knowledge these are indeed not available that far back for that many countries. Others might correct me.

Comment: Your best bet would be to go to actual or digitized libraries of central banks and other long standing institutions and go through the records. If you end up gathering all that information, you should start running a database with a 10-cent-per-view fee.